# java and threads: very strange behaviour

Tags: java, thread-safety

```
        private synchronized Map<Team, StandingRow> calculateStanding() {
          System.out.println("Calculate standing for group " + getName());
          Map<Team, StandingRow> standing = new LinkedHashMap<Team, StandingRow>();

          for (Team team : teams) {
           standing.put(team, new StandingRow(team));
          }

          StandingRow homeTeamRow, awayTeamRow;
          for (Match match : matches.values()) {

           homeTeamRow = standing.get(match.getHomeTeam());
           awayTeamRow = standing.get(match.getAwayTeam());

           System.out.println("Contains key for " + match.getHomeTeam() + ": " + standing.containsKey(match.getHomeTeam()));
           System.out.println("Contains key for " + match.getAwayTeam() + ": " + standing.containsKey(match.getAwayTeam()));
                }
        }
```

This is my code. matches contains 6 elements, but the problem is that after two matches no keys are anymore found in the standing map.

The output is for example

```
Contains key for Zuid-Afrika: true
Contains key for Mexico: true
Contains key for Uruguay: true
Contains key for Frankrijk: true
Contains key for Zuid-Afrika: false
Contains key for Uruguay: false
Contains key for Frankrijk: false
Contains key for Mexico: false
Contains key for Mexico: false
Contains key for Uruguay: false
Contains key for Frankrijk: false
Contains key for Zuid-Afrika: false
```

This is in a threaded environment, but the method is synchronized so I thought that this would not give a problem? I have also a simple unit test for this method and that works well.

Comment: This method does not even compile, as there is no return. Please show us the actual code.

Comment: Are the teams modified by some other thread? did you provide an implementation for both equals() and hashCode() in your Team class?

Answer (score 9):

This is almost surely not a threading issue. I'm all but certain that the problem is in your Team class. It's probably not implementing `hashCode()`/`equals()` the right way. Review the javadoc for these two methods and implement them accordingly.

Comment: He might be implementing them correctly. Because if he changes the `Team` object after using it as a key in a `Map`, then he will run into these problems even with correct implementations (especially with correct implementations, actually).

Comment: By the way: while the JavaDoc would be sufficient to implement them correctly if you're a genius, Chapter 3 of effective Java describes the problem and the solution in much more detail: http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/effectivejava/Chapter3.pdf

Comment: As Joachim said if Team is not immutable and used as key in a map there can be a problem even with a proper implementation of equals / hashcode

Answer (score 1):

Can you give the details of the `Team` and the `Match` classes?
Are they implementing `equals()` and `hashCode()`?

Since Team and Match are your own classes, you have to tell java how it should *match* (decide whether they are *equal*)

You do that using [`equals()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) and [`hashCode()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()). See also [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05273.html).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have implemented `equals()` and `hashCode()` [correctly](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05273.html), your method looks fine to me.

The big question is: Where does `teams` and `matches` come from and how are they filled?

If `teams` and `matches` are changed by different threads without synchronization on the same monitor, you could get race conditions there.

Try to sync the methods that are changing `matches` and `teams` also.